# How to fetch a SharePoint site information (Report)

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I'm trying to fetch a SharePoint site information (Report) i.e.

1. Get No.of SharePoint Subsites, Lists, documents or SitePages under a site.
2. List all the SharePoint Subsites, Lists, documents or SitePages under a site.
3. Owner of those SharePoint Subsites, Lists, documents or SitePages

using PowerShell.

I found some snippet to connect SharePoint Online using PowerShell for example.

**Below code for reference:-**

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell” -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null)
{
Add-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”
}
```

While running the above code in PowerShell ISE command prompt, below error was displayed

> Add-PSSnapin : No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell
>   version 5. At line:3 char:1
>   + Add-PSSnapin “Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell”
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell:String) [Add-PSSn     apin],
>   PSArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AddPSSnapInRead,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddPSSnapinCommand

Before running these commands on PowerShell ISE, is it necessary to Install **SharePoint Online Management Shell** tool.

Are there any other methods where we can generate these kind of reports other than PowerShell?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with the default sharepoint site report page(Site Content and Structure Manager).

Example:
https://sprnd.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite001/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx

Reference URL:

https://global-sharepoint.com/